# How can I capture a specific char inside specific strings with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I want to replace all the dots -that are inside specific strings- by underscores. In my case, I'm using i18n (for translations) inside my application, and the keys are called using  '$t(key)'.
Key can be like that :

```
key = 'translationKey'
key = 'translationKey.subkey.subSubkey'
key = 'translationKey.subkey.one'
key = 'translationKey.subkey.zero'
key = 'translationKey.subkey.others'
```

In the $t context: I want to transform the dots (.) that are not followed by `one` or `zero` or `others` into underscore (_). If I have those inputs :

```
foo.toto.anything
$t('translationKey')
$t('translationKey.subkey.subSubkey')
$t('translationKey.subkey.one')
$t('translationKey.subkey.zero')
$t('translationKey.subkey.others')
```

Then the output will be :

```
foo.toto.anything
$t('translationKey')
$t('translationKey_subkey_subSubkey')
$t('translationKey_subkey.one')
$t('translationKey_subkey.zero')
$t('translationKey_subkey.others')
```

I'd like to use Vscode regex search to capture those dots and to replace them (if possible).

I only managed to get all the strings where the target dots are, but I can't reach only the dots. Here's the the regex I have atm: `(\$|\.)t?t(c|p)?('(\w+\.?)*')`

Thank you

Comment: have you made an attempt?

Comment: @depperm I'm stuck actually because I only managed to get all the strings  where the target dots are, but I can't reach only the dots. Here's the the regex I have atm: 
    (\$|\.)t?t(c|p)?\('(\w+\.?)*'\)

Comment: @K450 thankyou but with that, you capture every other dots. Not only the ones that are inside $t(translationKey.subKey.etc);

Comment: Use `(?<=\$t\('[^']*)\.(?!(?:one|zero|others)')(?=[^']*'\))`. Please add the regex you used to the question body.

Comment: Perhaps you may do like `.replace(/\b\.(?!one|zero|other|$)/g,"_")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added the regex in the question. Can you provide an example using https://regex101.com/.  When I try it it seems your regex is not working :/

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/35K96i/1

Comment: This `((?<=\$t\('[^']*)\.(?!one|zero|others))` works as well

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks works fine. Know I'll adapt it to vscode :). Can you please add it as an answer so I make it the right answer for the question?

Comment: I posted the answer, just in case you missed the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?<=\$t\('[^']*)\.(?!(?:one|zero|others)')(?=[^']*'\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/35K96i/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=\$t\('[^']*)` - a positive lookbehind that requires `$t('` and then any zero or more chars other than `'` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?!(?:one|zero|others)')` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are `one'`, `zero'`, or `others'` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?=[^']*'\))` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than `'` and then `')`.

Comment: This works as expected :D. But in vscode I encountered an issue. While it"s working fine with local search, it doesn't for global search. I have the next message: "lookbehind assertion is not fixed length". So I think I'll implement a recursive find and replace using your regex :'(

Comment: @Kalukalu File search feature uses Rust regex engine, it does not support lookarounds. Lookarounds can only be used in the in-document search and replace tool.

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression should work: it matches all the dots not followed by "one", "others", and "zero"

```regex
(?<=\$t\('[^']+)\.(?!one|others|zero)
```

You can test it online here

https://regex101.com/r/84Jil1/1

Comment: Thank you but this capture all the dots. Not only the ones inside the $t context. For example if you do foo.to.hello. Your answer will also capture it. I'll update the question to be more clear about it

Comment: @Kalukalu, got it: I updated my answer